# Headless UI Automation Testing Using Coded UI

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, coded-ui-tests

As a *beginner*, I'm researching towards whether is it possible to run automated test scripts of Coded UI in **Headless** mode for **Azure DevOps** **CI/CD** pipeline.

My intention is to automate UI of Desktop Applications. Along with this, I have concerned about **MS Winapp Driver** as well but it was concluded that, Coded UI is the ideal tool for my objective.

***Researches Done:***

1.) Created a Coded UI project and run a test scenario through Visual Studio - Successful

2.) Run the same scenario (C# file) using **command prompt** (using MSTest switches) - Successful

It will be highly appreciable, if one can come up with some best solution(s) or sample project.

Comment: Coded UI has been deprecated, and VS 2019 will be the last version to support it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 2):

According to this link([UI testing considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest)), you can not use Headless for Desktop app.

> if you are running UI tests for desktop apps, Windows agents must be configured to run as an interactive process with auto-logon enabled

Comment: Thanks for the info @Shamrai Appreciate it